# How to prevent DrawReversibleFrame from drawing outside?

Tags: c#, frame, paint

How do I prevent DrawReversibleFrame from drawing outside of the SplitContainer and form as shown below?  As you can see, the selection frame is being drawn around a control within the container, which is bigger than the visible part of the container itself.

[resize image http://img84.imageshack.us/img84/8704/resizes.png](http://img84.imageshack.us/img84/8704/resizes.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SplitContainer.Panel2.Bounds gives you the rectangle of the portion of the right-hand side panel that's visible.